# If $f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{\sin(nx)}{4^n}$. Then value of $\int^{\pi}_{0}f(x)dx$ is

Tags: definite-integrals

> If $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{\sin(nx)}{4^n}$. Then value of $\displaystyle \int^{\pi}_{0}f(x)dx$ is

Plan

$$\int^{\pi}_{0}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{\sin(nx)}{4^n}dx=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{\sin(nx)}{4^n}dx$$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: What is wrong with carrying out your plan and at least getting an answer, even if it may be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term for $n=0$ vanishes, so it can be skipped, and for $n>0$ we have:
$$ \int_0^\pi \sin (nx) dx = \Big[\frac{-1}{n}\cos nx\Big]\Big|_{x=0}^{x=\pi} = \frac{1 - \cos (n\pi)}{n} = \frac{1-(-1)^n}{n}$$
You have then $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n} \int_0^\pi \sin (nx) dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n} \frac{1-(-1)^n}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1/4)^n-(-1/4)^n}{n}$$
You should be probably familiar with the formula $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n} = -\ln (1-z) $$
You have then 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1/4)^n-(-1/4)^n}{n} = -\ln(1-\frac14)+\ln(1+\frac14)=\ln\frac53$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Since $4^n$ does not depend on $x$, you need
$$
\int_0^\pi \sin(nx)dx
$$
which integrates using the substitution $u = nx$

Comment: There is one more thing that may be problematic for the OP. If they follow through with just getting a formula, they will eventually have a division by zero. (You wind up dividing by $n$, and then the zero term has a factor of $\dfrac{1}{n}$). One additional hint would be that $\sin(0x) = 0$ and $\int 0dx = 0$. This allows the problem to be treated as $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cdots$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\dfrac{\sin nx}{4^n}$ is the imaginary part of $\left(\dfrac{e^{ix}}4\right)^n$

As $\left|\dfrac{e^{ix}}4\right|=\dfrac14<1$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac{e^{ix}}4\right)^n=\dfrac1{1-\dfrac{e^{ix}}4}=\dfrac4{(4-\cos x)-i\sin x}$$

$$\implies f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin nx}{4^n}=\dfrac{4\sin x}{(4-\cos x)^2+\sin^2x}$$

Set $17-8\cos x=y,dy=8\sin x$

$$\implies2\int_0^\pi f(x)=\int_9^{25}\dfrac{dy}y=2\ln\dfrac53$$